# Converted Filter function into Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created filter function to Filter some sort of data `and it is working fine`  but later converted it to Query but i am stcuk on one thing that how to Filter the Date Column based on month values like (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12). I have created a Data validation for all 12 months.

your help will be much appreciated.

Filter Function:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Sheet1'!B:K,'Sheet1'!D:D=M4,month('Sheet1'!E:E)=X4),"No Data Available")
```

Query Function:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!B:K}, "SELECT * WHERE Col2 contains '"&J4&"' AND Col3 contains '"&M4&"' AND Col4 = month(date'"&text(X4,"M")&"') ORDER BY Col2 ASC",0)
```

Unable to make this Query line `AND Col4 = month(date'"&text(X4,"M")&"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!B:K}, "SELECT * WHERE Col2 contains '"&J4&"' AND Col3 contains '"&M4&"' AND month(Col4) ="&X4-1&" ORDER BY Col2 ASC",0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!B:K}, 
 "where Col2 contains '"&J4&"' 
    and Col3 contains '"&M4&"' 
    and month(Col4)+1 ="&X4&" 
  order by Col2", )
```

you can skip these:

- `select *` if you want to get all columns you can just skip `select` argument
- single quotes are needed only if sheet name contains a space
- months in query start from 0 (as January) so we just add `+1`
- when ordering its `asc` by default so we can skip it
- zero `0` as the 3rd argument can be omitted